# HIVE query to return last date of previous month

Tags: hive

How could I return the query for last day of previous month `yyyy-mm-dd` format in HIVE and also how to modify the code so that each month choose the last day?

Comment: what is the input data format? date or string? You can use last_day() to calculate last date of any month. Now, use add_monehs () to minus a month and then use last day. complete function will be `last_day(add_months(timestamp_col,-1))` this will give you a timestamp. Then you can use to_date to convert to string(hive ver <2.1).

Comment: The input data format is string